# RegularExpression Validator For Textbox

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

In my requirement a Textbox should allow Alphabets,Numeric s, Special Characters,Special Symbols With  `at least one Alphabet`.

I will try like this but i am not getting.

```
^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9#*,$._&% -!><^@]*$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just match for special characters until you encounter a letter, then match for everything until the end of the string:

```
^[0-9#*,$._&% -!><^@]*[a-zA-Z0-9#*,$._&% -!><^@]*$
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have 2 regular expression validators; one for validating the allowed characters, and one for validating that at least on alphabet has been provided.  You may be able to get at least one, but this way, you can have two separate validation messages to show the user explaining why the input is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use lookaheads :

```
/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[\w#*,$.&%!><^@-]*$/
```

Edit :

I assume the `-` is meant as the actual `-` character and not a range of  `space` to `!`.

I removed the space character. You can of course add it if you want.

```
[ -!]
```

Effectively means :

```
[ -!]    # Match a single character in the range between “ ” and “!”
```

And I have no idea what that range entails!